# Migrate ActiveMQ "Classic" Postgres data store to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ "Classic" in my project and need to update to Spring 6, Spring Boot 3 to use jakarta, but the ActiveMQ "Classic" client is not ready to use jakarta and Spring 6 requires jakarta connection and not javax connection.

So I decided to migrate to ActiveMQ Artemis and use the Artemis JMS client in my code because Artemis is already using jakarta.

But my ActiveMQ is using Postgresql store and I need to restart Artemis with the same store to not lose data. Are there tools to migrate `activemq_msgs` to new Artemis table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool to migrate data directly from the "Classic" tables to the Artemis tables.

The recommendation would be to stand up your ActiveMQ Artemis instance next to your existing ActiveMQ "Classic" instance and then set up a bridge (or collection of bridges) or perhaps even [a Camel route](https://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component) to move messages from one broker to another.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips i will try bridge or camel routing…but i habe many queue with dynamic prefix…so no simple;)